# How do I make sure all files are uploaded to Web Server when queuing a TFS build?

Tags: asp.net, fonts, tfs, tfsbuild

I have an asp.net project that has a fonts folder containing .ttf, .eot, .woff and .svg files.

After running the build, I check the web server and the .ttf, .eot and .woff files are not there.

I have also checked the drop folder, and it also does not contain those files.

All that can be found in the drop folder and web server are the .svg files.

**How do I make sure that all fonts are uploaded via TFS build functionality?**

Note: (Not sure if this would help) When you view the font files in solution explorer, the .eot and .woff file's icon appears like this icon https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/images/2012-11-13-19-11-25-ee0dc6.png - which should mean it is unrecognised. But the .ttf and .svg has their normal icons and is recognised.

Comment: On each files property is the Build Action set to Content?

Comment: @JustTFS - I am not sure, how do I check this? Fairly new to this.

Comment: Open your solution / project in visual studio. Click Properties. in the properties window you should see the list of properties. check that the Build Action is set to Content

Comment: @JustTFS I am not sure where to find the build action setting or Properties window you are talking about? In Solution Explorer if you second click a project, you can select properties there. When that window pops up I see a Build Tab but no Build Action setting. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Sorry, you need to check the property of each of the font files

Comment: @JustTFS - The files which are not being uploaded, the build action is set to None. I will change this, test it out and get back to ya :)

Comment: @JustTFS - Your solution worked, post answer and I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your solution / project in visual studio. For each font file that you want to include in the output, right click and select  Properties. In the properties window you should see the list of properties. Check that the Build Action is set to Content